# .Net Razor + Passing Raw HTML into @helper macro

Tags: .net, razor

I want to pass raw html into a @helper macro... is this possible?  For instance:

```
@helper oneColumn(string content) {
<div class="row">               
  <div class="twelve columns">
    @content                    
  </div>
</div>
}

@put.oneColumn(
  <h1 id="page-heading">HELLO WORLD!</h1>
)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
@helper oneColumn(Func<dynamic,HelperResult> content) {
<div class="row">               
  <div class="twelve columns">
    @content(null)                    
  </div>
</div>
}

@put.oneColumn( @<h1 id="page-heading">HELLO WORLD!</h1>)
```

Comment: This worked lite a charm for me! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If your new to razor templates, this should help explain `@put.oneColumn` [Creating and Using a Helper in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)

Comment: That solution only seems to work for 1 line. Not sure how to use this for multi-line html.

Comment: try the original askers' calling method that should work for multiple lines as long as the lines are all enclosed in a tag or `<text>` iirc. with my method signature style

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Html.Raw` HTML helper, or make content an `IHtmlString`.

Comment: @put.oneColumn(
  @Html.Raw(<h1 id="page-heading">HELLO WORLD!</h1>)
)  Invalid expression term '<'

Comment: @put.oneColumn(@IHtmlString(<h1 id="page-heading">My Goals</h1>))  Invalid expression term '<'

Comment: @put.oneColumn((<h1 id="page-heading">My Goals</h1>).ToString())  Invalid expression term '<'

Answer (score 0):

```
@helper oneColumn(string content) {
var contentHtml = new HtmlString(content);
<div class="row">               
  <div class="twelve columns">
    @contentHtml                    
  </div>
</div>
}

@put.oneColumn(
  "<h1 id=\"page-heading\">HELLO WORLD!</h1>"
)
```

Comment: The question was about passing raw HTML into the helper as an argument. Your argument here is a string, which requires escaping double quotes and other annoyances.